# Not able to init through phonegap build. Phonegap Inapp billing

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-billing

I am trying using this plugin(https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling). I added this in config.xml file and then uploaded  it to phonegap build

```
<gap:plugin name="com.smartmobilesoftware.inappbilling">
   <param name="BILLING_KEY" value="" />
</gap:plugin>
```

I did put my BILLING_KEY in the value above. But when I run the app. I am getting error like this

```
index 1 out of Range[0..1)
```

I tried console and it says key is undefined.

I send the key during init as in option like this

```
inappbilling.init(successHandler, errorHandler, {showLog:true,key:vkey});
```

where **vkey** contrain my Billing key string. Still I am not able to initialize the inAppbilling. Can anyone please tell what I am actually missing.

When I see my apk file. I can see the inappbilling.js file being included in the head. I can also see com.smartmobilesoftware.inappbilling directory with in the plugin.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same error, have you found any solution?

Comment: The issue exists on github : https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling/issues/93

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on GitHub:  The official PGB plugin for this repo is com.smartmobilesoftware.androidinappbilling